# How to move array from parent folder to new destination, while keeping same folder structure?

Tags: arrays, powershell, move

```
$srcRoot = (Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\Unsigned Items\*\*\* Archive' -Directory).FullName
```

Above is what I am using to get all of the files under multiple subfolders with the same name of "* Archive".

For example:

```
C:\Users\Nick\Documents\City 1\City 1 Archive
C:\Users\Nick\Documents\City 2\City 2 Archive
C:\Users\Nick\Documents\City 3\City 3 Archive
```

I am wanting to move all of the files within each of the "archive" subfolders to a different location like C:\Users\Documents\Archive

I want to retain the folder structure and to also keep in place the folder structure in the parent folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to create the folder structure prior to moving the files. Then you can loop through each item and do a `$_.Replace('C:\Unsigned Items','C:\Users\Nick\Documents')` as the target path for the move.

Answer (score 0):

All you would need to do is direct the move for the top folder:

```
Move-Item -Path "C:\Unsigned Items\*\*\* Archive"  -Destination "C:\Users\Documents\Archive" -WhatIf
```

This will retain the same folder structure after the move is completed.

---

*remove the `-WhatIf` parameter when you've dictated those are the results you're after*